# How to install "adb" on MacOSX?

Tags: android, adb

I searched Google and Stackoverflow and found some discussion on this. It's saying that there'd be an `adb` after installing Android SDKs.

But I don't have any `adb` command after installing. All I got is:

[image]

And some articles saying that use `brew install android-platform-tools` can work. I also tried but failed because it's telling me brew is not owned by root. I don't know where to find the `brew` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program or script `adb` is indeed part of the platform-tools.

While (home)brew may be a way to install those tools, I advise you to download it via Android's own SDK manager:

[image]

Look for the *Android SDK Platform-tools* entry and install that one.

---

If you really want to install it using homebrew, [install](http://brew.sh/) that first:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

and then use the `brew` command which comes with the homebrew installation:

```
brew install android-platform-tools
```

(ruby comes pre-packaged with the Mac OSX installation)

That **should** do the same (I haven't tried, so I don't know), but if you use the official Android SDK manager, you can be sure it works.

Comment: thanks, so `platform-tools` and what I've downloaded are totally two different things?

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo well, 'Android' has several components, one being the actual SDK with the source code etc, the regular tools, which you have listed in the pic in your question, the platform-tools, which are some other tools, and more. You can install/remove these components as you see fit. So they're not *entirely* different things, but they do offer seperate functions

Comment: Thanks I've accepted your answer. But one simple question: what is the difference of this "homebrew" `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"` with my current brew?

Comment: And I'm afraid I've already got homebrew, because I found it in my `usr/local` location. The problem is that I can't run it without root. but if I use su, it refuses to run...

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo `su` is not the same as `sudo`, which you probably should use. `su` starts an environment where everything you do has lifted superuser priveleges